# Transaction log shipping SQL Server 2005 to 2008

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, ssrs, transaction-log

I have a reporting setup with SSRS on our SQL Server 2005 database. Because SQL Server 2008 is not supported by the main program which populates our database we are stuck with 2005 on our production database. Unfortunately, when I run our weekly check reports the web interface constantly times out because the server can't do the conversion to PDF. I've read that SQL Server 2008's SSRS is A LOT better with memory management. I was wondering if I can do some kind transact log shipping subscription publication from 2005 to 2008? Am I chasing a dream here.

Currently I have to open up the SSRS project in Visual Studio and run the reports inside because it doesn't ever time out when doing the pdf conversion. It only times out if I try to run it through the SSIS web interface.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to log ship from SQL 2005 to SQL 2008 and be able to read the database.  When the database goes into standby mode it can't bring the database online because it can't upgrade the database's physical version.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both log shipping and replication support 2005 source -> 2008 target. If think SSRS 08 will solve your problem, why not setup a standalone instance of SSRS2008 and simply use the database on the 2005 server as the datasource?

You datasources do not have to be local to the SSRS installation. This would allow you to quickly test your proposed solution.

Comment: Excelent! My only problem is that because our domain is setup as mixed mode the SSRS instance has to be on the same machine as the database otherwise the users who access the reports get login errors as the dreaded double hop doesn't work just yet. We switched to exchange 2010 so I'm working on getting that solved but its confusing stuff.

Comment: You can create data sources within SSRS that will handle the authentication with the remote 2005 database, that way you aren't relying on the users authentication and you avoid the double hop issue.  And if security is a concern, you can control the permissions to the reports themselves (or grouped within folders) within the Report Manager.